# Dequeue messages from an ActiveMQ Virtual Topic

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, fuseesb

I'm using FuseESB with ActiveMQ v5.7.0.fuse-71-047 (aka v5.7)

I have one virtual topic "VirtualTopic.xxx" and one subscriber which (using Camel) it set ut as follows:

```
from(activemq:Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.xxx?brokerURL="something")
  .doSomething()
```

Eveything seems to run fine, and I can see messages being enqueued and dequeued from the
queue "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.xxx"

My question: Should messages dequeue from VirtualTopic.xxx ones they are sent to Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.xxx? Consumer A is the only subscriber. Using JConsole, I can see messages being enqueued but dequeue and dispatch count is 0. Is something wrong here?

Comment: Hi @KimAMartinsen . I am facing the same issue , were you able to find any resolution?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't. At least not as I can remember, it was a long time ago